# Does Ubuntu 16.04 support hybrid graphics cards (bumblebee)

Tags: bumblebee, 16.04, hybrid

Does Ubuntu 16.04 support hybrid graphics cards?
I ask because of the support of ubuntu snappy core in Ubuntu 16.04.

I use bumblebee to start, for example a game, in better graphics quality.
(optirun ./start.sh)

[Link to bumblebee](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee)

Does that work with Ubuntu 16.04?

Comment: this same issue happens on Ubuntu 17.10 luckily the acknowledged answer below solves it

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I got it working after some trying (nvidia-364, from ubuntu graphics ppa).

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install nvidia-364

sudo apt-get install bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia primus linux-headers-generic

sudo systemctl enable bumblebeed
```

After that `sudo gedit /etc/modules`
and add 2 lines:

```
i915
bbswitch
```

then

```
sudo prime-select intel

sudo gedit /etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf
```

in line 22: `Driver=nvidia`

Make sure to change lines change every `nvidia-current` to `nvidia-364` (or whatever version you have).

After that, you can safely reboot your computer.

Comment: Works verry well. 
But important is, to remove bumlebee and nvidia before restarting the system.

`sudo apt-get purge nvidia* bumblebee`

Comment: You should also `sudo apt-get install nvidia-prime` as well as `nvidia-364` otherwise `prime-select` will not be available. It wasn't obvious to me that I could install both `bumblebee` and `nvidia-prime`, although this seems to be essential on my machine.

Comment: Once I get to the point where I should prime-select intel, I am being told that that nvidia-prime needs to be installed... doing this however uninstalls the bumblebee packages. How did you manage to install both simultaneously?

Answer (score 10):

Bumblebee had no development since 2013 and is deprecated in 16.04, installation of `nvidia-361` and `nvidia-prime` should take care of the bumblebee functionality. pilot6 gave the usage details [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/661924/332437).

Don't let the "it's broken" comment influence you. There were lots of improvements in the meantime.

Comment: This pretty much sums it up.
sudo apt-get install nvidia-361 nvidia-prime
will add the functionality.

Comment: `nvidia-prime` has nowhere near the functionality of `primus`

Comment: the nvidia-prime approach is seemless , you don't have to switch it enables the nivida bits when you need them. It looks like its not using nvidia but is conspicously fast.

Comment: I have Ubuntu 16.04 and Bumblebee is working ok for me.

Comment: @AidanEdwards Like which functionality?

Comment: @jarno Sorry, I can't remember. I haven't had that hybrid setup since the beginning of the school year.

Comment: Fixed broken system suspend where waking to black screen last three days. One of the steps was `System Settings` -> `Software and Updates` -> `Additional Drivers` and deselect "Nividia proprietary 304` and select `Nvidia proprietary 375` forgot the `prime-select` step but did that after reboot with <ctrl>+<alt>+F2 console screen. +1 in case this helps others. Note I did three other things in same session so can't guarantee this fix is ultimate reason my suspend/resume is normal now.

Answer (score 3):

Still nothing on the vsync problem. We'll need kernel 4.5, xorg patch (1.19) and nvidia patch.

You can follow up the thread here.

https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/775691/linux/vsync-issue-nvidia-prime-ux32vd-with-gt620-m-/3

Comment: So in kernel 4.5 and new xorg there would be finally no tearing! Sweet!

Answer (score 2):

The bumblebee version in the repos and the default nvidia-361 driver do not work.  You either have to install an older nvidia driver and manually edit multiple config files or install bumblebee and nvidia drivers from ppa's and  also manually edit files.  The alternative is to use nvidia-prime to switch graphics drivers but this requires that you log out each time.  Bumblebee works out of the box in several other distros  so its disappointing to have to jump through so many hoops to get it working in a major distro like ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways to enable the Optimus technique. Bumblebee is just one of the solution for some supported computers. See [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/766745/do-i-need-to-install-bumblebee-for-hybrid-graphics-system-to-enable-optimus-on-u) with a link to the official [Ubuntu wiki page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/HybridGraphics). If you prefer to use Bumblebee, I suggest to wait for the Version 4.0 to come (soon) to avoid NVidia driver compatibility problems. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it’s supported. As Huba Buba pointed out, they are some issues that should be solved in the coming 4.0 version of Bumblebee. A pre-version is available through our [testing PPA](https://launchpad.net/~bumblebee/+archive/ubuntu/testing), if you test it please take a look at https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee/issues/749, 759 and 761. Report your results here to tell us whether you still need editing of the bumblebee.conf file.

Also, note that the prime-select command (and thus installation of nvidia-prime) are not needed at all. And while you can install both, making both work together is a bit more complicated.