# Ubuntu 16.04 Nvidia GeForce 940M black screen after suspend

Tags: nvidia, graphics, suspend, resume

I just purchased an ASUS laptop that has the Nvidia GeForce 940M GFX card in it. Ubuntu installed the Nvidia 361 driver and it works fine. Computer boots up using the Nvidia graphics. The problem is when I try to resume from suspend. The screen looks lit but nothing shows. I can't open another virtual terminal thus leaving my only option is to force shutdown the computer by means of holding the power button for 6 seconds.

For the moment, I just disabled the "suspend on lid close" setting so I'm stuck just shutting down my computer before I travel with it. Not that big of I deal considering the awesome graphics (first GPU in a decade). However, if this is something that can be solved I'd obviously want to.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to the club. old problem with no solution.

Depend on what you are doing with your laptop, you should consider switching to intel graphic in Nvidia X server settings.

The better solution would be to install bumblebee to be able to run a specific program with dedicated GPU ([This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/758972/does-ubuntu-16-04-support-hybrid-graphics-cards-bumblebee) is helpful for bumblebee installation).

Again, it really depends what you want to do. If you are going to code CUDA, bumblebee might be useful if you run the IDE with bumblebee. If you want to use any code generator for it, bumblebee is not suitable for you (based on my own experience) and you should bear with suspend issue and screen tearing (and probably over heating).

If you just want to do day-to-day regular jobs and live you life with your laptop happily, forget about your dedicated graphic and switch to intel graphic forever.

Hope this helped.