# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS: Black screen after suspending/putting screen down on Lenovo E540 laptop

Tags: graphics, suspend, laptop, lenovo

My computer specs are:

- Graphics: Intel® Haswell Mobile
- Processor: Intel® Core™ i7-4702MQ CPU @ 2.20GHz × 8

I have just reinstalled Ubuntu 16.04 on my Lenovo E540 laptop and am loving it, except for the black screen I get after suspending/closing and reopening my laptop, without anything I can do but restarting it by force (not even <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Delete</kbd> works).

I am aware that this thread already exists, but there seems to be no working answer yet for Ubuntu 16.04, other than Yugi's answer to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/793347/ubuntu-16-04-nvidia-geforce-940m-black-screen-after-suspend) thread, which to me sounds like hocus pocus:

> Again, it really depends what you want to do. If you are going to code CUDA, bumblebee might be useful if you run the IDE with bumblebee.

What does that mean?

Finally I have tried to update the BIOS, which did not work.

For now I simply do not use the *Suspend* button, and I have set the power settings to *do nothing* when lid is closed.

How can I fix the issue?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Does your laptop have a dual GPU setup? I.e. NVIDIA and Intel cards? The question you linked clearly refers to that situation.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to press Space, like when Windows goes to sleep

Comment: Yes, the screen is supposed to go black after waking from sleep, and it should wake up when pressing space or enter, unless there's a more serious problem. OP said ctrl-alt-del doesn't work.