# Ubuntu 16.04 Nvidia Prime - Resume from suspend to black screen

Tags: 16.04, nvidia, suspend

laptop = [acer aspire](http://www.notebookcheck.net/Acer-Aspire-V3-572PG-604M-Notebook-Review.128525.0.html)

cpu = intel i3-4050U

gpu = nvidia 840m

Vanilla offline install. On first boot I do updates. I reboot again and then install nvidia 361 & nvidia-prime. I reboot again.

Everything seems fine except:

On Intel graphics, suspend is flawless and very fast.

On nVidia graphics, suspend resumes to black unresponsive screen. Tty's don't work. Only way to get back to working system is to hard reset.

I need to use GPU, so just not using it isn't really ideal. Changing them requires a really lengthy logout process. System has a 500gb evo 850 ssd, but the logout takes 43 seconds.

I am looking for a way to fix resume from suspend while using the GPU, or a way to make the change over of graphics much faster [less than 5 seconds].

I am not sure which logs to post to help with the situation.

The only other changes I have made is to use that script going around to fix reconnecting to WiFi after resume from suspend.

As an option I would have no problem just leaving the GPU active all the time [I don't care about battery life, it's always plugged in.] But only if resume from suspend worked, as using a laptop without suspend working is really painful. It's built into my "muscle memory" to just close the lid and forget about it.

Kind thanks for anyone who can point me in the right direction.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/758972/does-ubuntu-16-04-support-hybrid-graphics-cards-bumblebee