# Ubuntu 16.04 only works when secondary monitor is connected

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, multiple-monitors, vga

I have Ubuntu 16.04 on a Gigabyte Aero 14 laptop having Geforce GTX 1060 VGA. Using different nvidia drivers results in different behavior. For example, "nvidia-384" and "nvidia-387" don't detect the second monitor.

Currently, I have installed `nvidia-390` (tried both .run file from nvidia website, and the package from `ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa`). It works when the external monitor is attached, but when I disconnect the monitor and reboot, ubuntu crashes after login.

Some notes:

- I have already tried [Ubuntu 16.04 + Nvidia Driver = Blank screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760374/ubuntu-16-04-nvidia-driver-blank-screen/763302#763302)
- Reinstalled drivers
- Tried both UEFI disabled and enabled
- Tried Unity and Gnome
- Nouveau driver, nvidia-367, nvidia-384, and nvidia-387 don't detect my second monitor
- Tried both mini-display to VGA port, and HDMI to HDMI
- `sudo lshw -c video` result: https://pastebin.com/raw/pZmkDbWC
- CPU Info: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6700HQ CPU @ 2.60GHz
- BIOS info: [image]
- In BIOS, the only option related to VGA I see is 3D Graphic Acceleration
  [image]

Comment: What exactly does "ubuntu crashes after login" mean?

Comment: It freezes after I enter my password and press enter. Mouse cursor doesn't move, and keyboard (e.g. Ctrl+Alt+F1, Num-Lock) doesn't work. I have to turn off and on the laptop by long pressing the power key.

Answer (score 1):

You appear to have an Intel "Skylake" CPU in your [Gigabyte Aero 14 laptop.](https://www.gigabyte.com/Laptop/AERO-14--GTX-1060#sp) The Skylake has integrated Intel graphics and unless I'm mistaken is used by default to drive the primary (non-external) monitor. [Issues have been reported with screens freezing related to the Skylake line of mobile processors.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/248972/xorg-on-skylake-graphics-hangs) Considering everything you've already tried and the results you've reported I think it's safe to say that this may be a kernel issue and not the usual graphics driver issue. Make sure you do not have nomodeset or vga= [as a kernel parameter,](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19486/how-do-i-add-a-kernel-boot-parameter) since Intel requires kernel mode-setting.

It could also be useful to temporarily try `intel_idle.max_cstate=1` as a kernel boot parameter.

You might also [reconfigure X.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/159663/how-to-reset-the-xorg-xserver)

**EDIT:**
Since your laptop has Optimus Graphics technology you might need to install [nvidia-prime or bumblebee](https://askubuntu.com/questions/877651/nvidia-prime-or-optimus) and check your BIOS display setting to obtain the desired results (as it's unclear at least to me whether you've selected a specific display adapter or are using a hybrid graphics setting .

You might also obtain some clues from [this question.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/805199/prime-profiles-tab-missing-in-nvidia-x-server-settings-ubuntu-16-04?rq=1)

It's also possible that in your numerous attempts to find the right graphics driver for your situation that you may have inadvertently created something of a mess in which case you might find [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/481540/225694) particularly useful.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Adding intel_idle.max_cstate=1 as a kernel boot parameter and reconfiguring X solved the "login" problem, but the screen freezes just after login after rendering desktop. Also, about nvidia-prime and bumblebee, aren't these just to select a VGA for a specific program? How they help to resolve this issue?
By the way, about the CPU that's right. It is:
Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6700HQ CPU @ 2.60GHz

Comment: @Saber typically there's a setting in the BIOS related to how the display adapters are handled. Please [edit] your post to include what setting you are using and which you've tried with the current configuration. Thank you for helping us help you!